# Capistrano Cap Deploy issue with RVMRC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, rvm, capistrano

So I run cap deploy to try and deploy to ec2, and get this issue:

```
 ** [ec2-54-200-24-60.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com :: out] * RVM has encountered a new or modified .rvmrc file in the current           *
 ** * directory, this is a shell script and therefore may contain any shell      *
 ** * commands.                                                                  *
 ** *                                                                            *
 ** * Examine the contents of this file carefully to be sure the contents are    *
 ** * safe before trusting it!                                                   *
 ** * Do you wish to trust '/var/www/highlandsfbart#/shared/cached-copy/.rvmrc'? *
 ** * Choose v[iew] below to view the contents                                   *
 ** [ec2-54-200-24-60.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com :: out] ******************************************************************************
 ** [ec2-54-200-24-60.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com :: out] y[es], n[o], v[iew], c[ancel]>
```

However, when I type y and press enter, it hangs and nothing happens.  Same when i type v and enter.

I tried modifying the .rvmrc file in my (local) project folder as such, but this didn't do anything.

```
rvm_trust_rvmrcs_flag=1
```

I also tried adding this code to my deploy.rb, but still no luck:

```
namespace :rvm do
  desc 'Trust rvmrc file'
  task :trust_rvmrc do
    run "rvm rvmrc trust #{current_release}"
  end
end

after "deploy:update_code", "rvm:trust_rvmrc"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to run it on every server as user:

```
echo rvm_trust_rvmrcs_flag=1 | sudo tee -a /etc/rvmrc
```

or as root:

```
echo rvm_trust_rvmrcs_flag=1 >> /etc/rvmrc
```

Comment: This seems to work, however I still get the following:  ** [ec2-54-200-24-60.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com :: out] cannot create directory `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@tedxperth'
 ** [ec2-54-200-24-60.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com :: out] : Permission denied.  Any ideas?

Comment: that's a new question ... are you sure your user is in `rvm` group? you should try https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano - `before 'deploy', 'rvm:create_gemset'`